# scab on cats head

Tags: cats, wound-care

my one year old cat has a red scab on the side of her head by her eye. she had another one on the other side but it pretty much healed and went away and had another on the side of her neck but that one looks much less concerning and healing i think

i first noticed it a week ago and i checked again today and it looks worse than it did last week. my dad thinks it’s from playing with my other cat and it is just a scab but i’m not sure her and my other cat are my first cats and they have never had any injuries anything besides this

whenever i touch it or look at it she does not react or seem in pain at all and she has no other symptoms and acts perfectly normal and i do not see her trying to touch it or anything either, i just have no idea where it came from.

should i be concerned and take her to a vet or is it ok and just let it heal on its own or use stuff at home to help? please let me know anything on if i need to take her somewhere !

Comment: A photo might help.

Comment: You could also try to call a vet and ask, if you can send a photo. Then ypu have experienced meaning about the scab.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely (albeit not definite) that it is caused by someones claws--could be her own or the other cat. It is even more likely if your cats are indoor only (if they go outside, obviously there are more ways she could get a scratch/scab like that).

If it is in the same spot on both sides of her head, she could be trying to scratch her ears and is hurting herself. My cat sometimes has scratches/scabs in a similar area and the vet thinks her itchy ears are the way her allergies manifest. As long as it is healing, it's probably fine, but checking with the vet is always best.

You could also make sure to keep both of their claws trimmed regularly so that these types of scratches are less likely to happen.